# how to display vtk 3D axes on screen?

Tags: python-2.7, vtk

Is there any methods for display the vtk 3D axes at a specific place (such as left bottom) on the screen? I have tried to use the vtktransform but it does accepts the coordinates of the world only, but not the screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

If yes, then you can use `vtkOrientationMarkerWidget` and `vtkAxesActor` to do that. Have a look at [this](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Visualization/DisplayCoordinateAxes/) link, it might help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks. In addition to the widget I used SetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5) to get the whole data visible in the renderwindow.

Comment: I had the same issue. As shown in the link, be sure to reset the camera after adding the axes widget: `renderer->ResetCamera();`.

Comment: The posted link with example code isn't valid anymore, but [this one](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Interaction/CallBack/) works at the moment of writing.